# How to convert NSDictionary to NSData to generate QRCode

Tags: encoding, nsdictionary, nsdata, qr-code

I want to generate qrcode for a NSDictionary. Using NSKeyedArchiver converted dictionary to NSData and generated a QRCode. But when the qrcode is scanned the output is of different characters with the dictionary element in somewhere in between the output.

Is there a way to use DataUsingEncoding to convert dictionary to data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you give some code, because `QRCode` for a `NSDictionary` seems quite weird. QRCode will render a String, no? A sample of your initial Dictionary, and the wanted result could help.

Comment: I have multiple strings. so am using NSDictionary. the dictionary contains URL path,Customer ID and password. The result should be a qrcode.

Comment: Could you give some sample of the input, and wanted output?

Comment: To Generate QRCode:-
 
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    
    [dict setValue:[Utility customerID] forKey:@"CI"];
    
    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:dict];
    
    CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIQRCodeGenerator"];
    
    [filter setValue:data forKey:@"inputMessage"];
    [filter setValue:@"Q" forKey:@"inputCorrectionLevel"];
    
    qrcodeImage = filter.outputImage;
    
    _imgQRCode.image = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:qrcodeImage];

Comment: It may be better to use JSON instead of `NSKeyedArchiver` to transform your dictionary into a NSString. Also, please put your code in your question (edit), not in comment where it's not formatted and hard to read.

Comment: Thanks alot that worked.